# How to 'notice' a widget to do something in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter web page that returns different containers base on user selections. How do I select a different tab (D) inside tab (C) when something is done is tab (C)?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Holding Page', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                setTabs(1, 'Tab A', this), //setTabs set appearance and assign _selectedTab value for SetContainer
                setTabs(2, 'Tab B', this),
                setTabs(3, 'Tab C', this),
                setTabs(4, 'Tab D', this),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            SetContainer(this),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget SetContainer(obj) {
  void _changeTab(){
    print('hit');
    _selectedTab = 4;
    obj.setTab();
  }
  switch (_selectedTab) {
    case 3:
      {
        return ImportExcel(
          voidCallback: _changeTab,
        );
      }
      break;

    default:
      return Text('');
  }
}

class ImportExcel extends StatefulWidget {
   final Function voidCallback;
   ImportExcel({required this.voidCallback});
....

ElevatedButton(
          //sample usage by passing it to the onPressed value of an ElevatedButton
            onPressed: () {
              widget.voidCallback;
            },
            child: Text('Am a VoidCallback')),
```

What I would like is when finished operation in ImportExcel(), the screen jumps to ImportLog() automatically.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be to pass a callback to `ImportExcel`, which it would call when the operation is complete. Then inside the callback, you could call `setState` on your parent widget to change the tab.

Something like:

```dart
return ImportExcel(
    onComplete: () {
        setState(() {
            _selectedTab = 4;
        });
    },
);
```

Comment: Thanks bards, I should I handle onComplete() then?

Comment: I modified as follows: Widget SetContainer(obj) {
  void _changeTab(){
    print('hit');
    _selectedTab = 4;
    obj.setTab();
  }

return ImportExcel(
          voidCallback: _changeTab,
        );

Comment: and I added a test button in ImportExcel:
ElevatedButton(
          //sample usage by passing it to the onPressed value of an ElevatedButton
            onPressed: () {
              widget.voidCallback;
            },
            child: Text('Am a VoidCallback')),

Comment: but it seems doesn't hit

Comment: @TonyLam the code is difficult to read in a comment; can you please add your fully updated code (all the relevant bits) to the bottom of your question and then comment here to let me know, so I can see it properly?

Comment: First, you’re not actually calling widget.voidCallback. You need to add the () to call it. Second, you may need to use setState to set the tab, unless obj.setTab() is supposed to go that (not sure why you wouldn’t just use setState though)